# VBA More Efficient/Cleaner way to select sheet and assign variables to cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this which will compile quicker and look better/be less lines:

```
Sheets("Parameters").Select
PlateNo = Cells(1, 2).Value
Startrow = Cells(2, 2).Values
Startcol = Cells(3, 2).Value
ColNo = Cells(4, 2).Value
Step = Cells(5, 2).Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using Select/Activate where possible (and you almost never *need* to use them...)

```
With Sheets("Parameters").Columns(2)
    PlateNo = .Cells(1).Value
    Startrow = .Cells(2).Value
    Startcol = .Cells(3).Value
    ColNo = .Cells(4).Value
    StepNo = .Cells(5).Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I remembered that select is usually unnesecary.